# Purpose of requirePermission attribute (web.config)

Tags: .net, asp.net

What does the `requirePermission` attribute in the `<section>` element do?

For example:

```
<configuration> 
  <configSections> 
    <section name="urlrewritingnet"   
             restartOnExternalChanges="true" 
             requirePermission ="false"  
             type="UrlRewritingNet.Configuration.UrlRewriteSection, 
                   UrlRewritingNet.UrlRewriter" /> 
  </configSections> 
</configuration>
```

There is no mention of this attribute in the [official documention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228245.aspx). But, seems to be used in a lot of places.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The behaviour resulting from this setting is documented at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.sectioninformation.requirepermission.aspx.

Answer (score 8):

I'm actually going to quote the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.sectioninformation.requirepermission.aspx) just in case that page disappears as part of MSDN cleanup.

> When RequirePermission is set to true, the GetSection methods are
>   restricted by the trust level setting of the application. This means
>   that methods or properties that allow access to configuration section
>   handlers are restricted by the trust level set for the Web
>   application. NoteNote
>
> **NOTE:** Because high and full trust are the only levels that allow access to
>   files outside the current application domain, an application can use
>   configuration section handlers only at these trust levels.
>
> When RequirePermission is set to false, the access to the
>   configuration data is not restricted by the application's trust level
>   settings. NoteNote
>
> **NOTE:** The appropriate file ACL (Access Control List) permissions are still
>   required, regardless of the RequirePermission setting. ACL permissions
>   determine who can access the configuration file.